# Addresses in /proc/self/maps are way too high

Tags: linux, memory

I'm creating a "mod" for a game (namely CS:GO). I'm parsing `/proc/self/maps` in order to get the address of `client.so`. However, the addresses returned by it are in the range of 100000gib. I've read that the 3 trailing zeros may be problematic but even removing them it's still around 32gib, which would be nice if I didn't have only 16gib of ram. What gives?

Comment: **Those addresses are virtual** and are not limited by or related to your physical memory

Comment: With ASLR, the `.so` could be almost anywhere in virtual memory. Have you tried it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: Have you tried using `dlopen()` instead?

Comment: I've read up on aslr/virtual memory and I think I mostly understand it now, but my question is now what should I do about it? I can't think of a method for getting around it, and I've tried various tricks to disable it (`setarch \`uname -m\` -R $SHELL`), but nothing works.

Comment: Getting around what? What exactly are you trying to do? What do you want to do with the addresses you get?

Comment: I'm trying to read/write to some specific memory, ie LocalPlayer. With winapi it's as simple as calling `getModuleHandle("client.dll")` and adding some offset to get a pointer to LocalPlayer or something else. When I do the equivalent on linux (with https://github.com/softdevteam/phdrs), I get a segfault (which makes sense).

Comment: Then you probably want [`dlopen` and `dlsym`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) (or link directly with `client.so`)